# Is there anyway to keep the attributes of NSAttributedString when it is localized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to localize a NSAttributedString.

However, I found the **attributes of the NSString all gone after localization**.

Is there anyway to **keep** those attributes?

```
self.doctorUITextView.attributedText = NSLocalizedString([doctorNSMutableAttributedString string], nil);
```

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile. Please post valid code in your question. You can't assign an `NSString` to a property expecting `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @rmaddy This is actually where the problem lies. Attributes of the NSString all gone after localization because it can only return a NSString but I need a NSAttributedString for the attributedText.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Create a method which creates NSAttributedString every time you need to update `textView`'s content

```
- (void) setDoctorText: (NSString *) string {
    //create your attributes dict
    UIFont *keyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:16];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:keyFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    _doctorTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
}
```

Usage:

```
[self setDoctorText:NSLocalizedString(@"your string", @"")];
```

instead of this:

```
_doctorTextView.attributedText = @"your string";
```

**Solution 2:**

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can create `NSMutableAttributedString` property and set it's attributes once in `viewDidLoad`. Then whenever you need to update `textView`'s text, you just do it through stored mutable attributed text.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *doctorTextView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableAttributedString *doctorAttributedString;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIFont *keyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:16];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:keyFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    _doctorAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" " attributes:attributes];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _doctorAttributedString.mutableString.string = NSLocalizedString(@"your string", @"");
    _doctorTextView.attributedText = _doctorAttributedString;
}

@end
```